# Binding Square bracket [ with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to bind the left square bracket [, to my tkinter text widget.
I've looked through the docs and forums several times and tried all combinations I could think of. Control-Alt-Key-8, Key-bracketleft, Key-topleftsqbracket, etc.
Does anyone know?

I've tried the following:
I've also tried binding it with the root.

```
root = Tk()

text = Text(root)

text.pack()

def complete_it(evt=None):
    print('You pressed "[" ')

text.bind('[', complete_it)
text.bind("[", complete_it)
text.bind('<[>', complete_it)
text.bind("<[>", complete_it)
text.bind("<Control-Alt-8>", complete_it)
text.bind("<Control-Alt-Key-8>", complete_it)
text.bind("<bracketleft>", complete_it)
text.bind('<Control-Alt-8>', complete_it)
text.bind('<Control-Alt-Key-8>', complete_it)
text.bind("<Key-[>", complete_it)
text.bind("<topleftsqbracket>", complete_it)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You want to bind a text bracket in the text widget or the bracket key to the text widget?

Comment: I want to bind the bracket key to the text widget.
So that when I press the [, I want my command to be activated.

Comment: Please show what you've tried by creating a [mcve].

Comment: Do you have a keyboard configured for a language other than english? Without your binding, when you press `[` in a text widget, does it insert `[`?

Comment: I do have my keyboard in another language yes, Swedish, however, when I press then [ button, I do get the symbol in the text widget. I am able to bind to pretty much every character except the square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

That is very simple just use `text.bind('[', lambda evt: func)`. [See this site for more details](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

**Example:**

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

text = Text(root)
text.pack()

def complete_it(evt=None):
    print('You pressed "[" ')

text.bind('[', complete_it)

mainloop()
```

This bind will work only when the text widget is in focus. If you want the bind to work always use `root.bind()` instead.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for quick response, but that actually doesn't work for me.
Neither with root.bind nor text.bind.
The ( symbol works fine but not the square brackets.

Comment: Can you please share some code so we can see exactly where is the problem. You can edit your post and add more to it.

Comment: @VictorKrook: just to be clear, are you saying that _this exact code_ doesn't work for you?

Comment: Yes, I've literally copied the exact code from above and tried it. All other combinations work, except the [, it's very weird.

Comment: @VictorKrook in order it to work you have to have your text widget in focus as text widget loses it focus when clicked somewhere else , try type "[" in the text widget and see your console. Do you see anything like _You pressed "["_ ?

Comment: The text widget has focus when I press "[" and it's inserted in the text widget.

Comment: I just ran the exact code and it is working fine. I really don't understand why it's not working for you.

Comment: Okay, I don't know neither, it's very weird, still not working.

Comment: @VictorKrook Now I'm very curious to know how this is not working for you. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55838002/edit) your post and add more details like the exact code you are trying and a screenshot of something relevant.